# How to prevent Monkey test from opening notification panel and turning OFF wifi?

Tags: android, automated-tests, monkey, monkey-testing

I am performing Monkey testing on my Android app. 
While performing events, Monkey pulls down the notification panel and clicks on wifi/mobile data icons, hence turning them OFF.

I am using this command: **adb shell monkey -p package_name --throttle 100 -s 999 -v 50000**

I have tried all the options given here: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html

Is there any way to prevent Monkey test from opening notification panel?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve this problem:

```
--pct-touch 100 --pct-syskeys 0
```